# Inverting an angle on the Y-axis, X works

Tags: c++, game-physics

I've asked this question over at GameDev but got not response so far and this question is a bit time sensitive unfortunately.

I'm pretty sure this is just me doing something stupid or not understanding something that I should but I cannot figure out what is wrong here.

I'm having a problem bouncing a projectile off a sprite, we've been asked to move the projectile using the equations of motions which makes things a little more difficult but as far as I can see what I have should work.

What I'm trying to do is change the angle of the collided projectile depending on which direction it is coming from.

Here is a video that is hopefully not too laggy for you to see what is happening:

[Link](http://screencast.com/t/5txSOYBan)

When the projectile collides with the left or right hand side of the sprite everything works as expected, it just switches X direction.

When it hit's the top or bottom of the sprite however it doesn't change, it just sort of rolls along the top and the shoots off.

Here is the movement code:

```
float nX = get_x() + cos(nGetAngle() * 3.14 / 180) * getU() * getT();
float nY = get_y() - sin(nGetAngle() * 3.14 / 180) * getU() * getT() + 0.5 * 9.8 * getT() * getT();
set_world_position(nX, nY);
```

Where U is initial velocity, T is time and nGetAngle() is the angle in degrees (which is set to radians whenever the angle is set).

Here is my collision for the top of the player:

//if the projectile is colliding in any way with the player sprite

```
if (projectiles[currProj]->get_y() < player->get_y()) // top of player
{
    float vx = cos(projectiles[currProj]->nGetAngle());
    float vy = sin(projectiles[currProj]->nGetAngle());

    float newAngle = atan2(-vy, vx) * 180 / 3.14;

    projectiles[currProj]->nSetAngle(newAngle);
    projectiles[currProj]->set_world_position_y(player->get_y() - projectiles[currProj]->get_height() - 1);
}
```

and here is my collision for the left of the player:

```
else if (projectiles[currProj]->get_x() < player->get_x()) // left of player
{
    projectiles[currProj]->set_world_position_x(player->get_x() - projectiles[currProj]->get_width());

    float vx = cos(projectiles[currProj]->nGetAngle());
    float vy = sin(projectiles[currProj]->nGetAngle());

    float newAngle = atan2(vy, -vx) * 180 / 3.14;

    projectiles[currProj]->nSetAngle(newAngle);
}
```

The left side collision works, the top does not and I have no idea why.

If necessary I can post the entire project somewhere.

Full collision code for player:

```
void Game::playerCollision()
{
    if (projectiles[currProj]->bb_collision(player))
    {
        if (projectiles[currProj]->get_y() < player->get_y()) // top of player
        {
            float vx = cos(projectiles[currProj]->nGetAngle());
            float vy = sin(projectiles[currProj]->nGetAngle());


            float newAngle = atan2(-vy, vx) * 180 / 3.14;

            projectiles[currProj]->nSetAngle(newAngle);
            projectiles[currProj]->set_world_position_y(player->get_y() - projectiles[currProj]->get_height() - 1);
        }
        else if (projectiles[currProj]->get_y() + projectiles[currProj]->get_height() > player->get_y() + player->get_height() + 1) // bottom of player
        {
            projectiles[currProj]->set_world_position_y(player->get_y() + player->get_height());
            float vx = cos(projectiles[currProj]->nGetAngle());
            float vy = sin(projectiles[currProj]->nGetAngle());

            float newAngle = atan2(-vy, vx) * 180 / 3.14;

            projectiles[currProj]->nSetAngle(newAngle);
        }
        else if (projectiles[currProj]->get_x() < player->get_x()) // left of player
        {

            projectiles[currProj]->set_world_position_x(player->get_x() - projectiles[currProj]->get_width());

            float vx = cos(projectiles[currProj]->nGetAngle());
            float vy = sin(projectiles[currProj]->nGetAngle());

            float newAngle = atan2(vy, -vx) * 180 / 3.14;

            projectiles[currProj]->nSetAngle(newAngle);
        }

        else if (projectiles[currProj]->get_x() > player->get_x()) // right of player
        {
            projectiles[currProj]->set_world_position_x(player->get_x() + player->get_width());

            float vx = cos(projectiles[currProj]->nGetAngle());
            float vy = sin(projectiles[currProj]->nGetAngle());

            float newAngle = atan2(vy, -vx) * 180 / 3.14;

            projectiles[currProj]->nSetAngle(newAngle);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through the code during a collision?

Comment: I have, the problem is I don't really know what I'm looking for.

The collision happens, it's not being skipped or anything, the angle changes from a positive to a negative which I think makes sense.

I just can't understand why hitting the side works perfectly but the top fails every time.

Comment: Please post the complete if-else-if chain of your collision detection. there may be a flaw in detecting which collision happend.

Comment: added the full collision code for the player.

Comment: Do you remember that *tan(a) =  tan(a+180°)* for any angle *a*? You have to determine the quarter of your initial angle and check if +180° has to be added to the `atan2`'s result.

Comment: I didn't remember that, if I every knew it (really bad at this), what do you mean by quarter?

Answer (score 0):

I think your collision detection is not sufficient. without knowing your representation in detail

- you do not check where the projectile (pr) came from. a collision top left within the player (pl) might have entered through the top or from the left
- you do not bounce the pr immediately, you just alter the direction. depending on the entry depth it might not be able to exit with the next iteration. this happens especially on the top where the pr accelerates downwards but slows down upwards.

so you must

- detect the entry surface (determines angle)
- and most important rebounce immediately

Comment: I've tried removing all other collision checks so that only the projectile hitting it at the top is considered, the set_world_position should be taking care of the entry depth, it moves the projectile so that it's bottom side is touching the top-side of the player and then moves it by 1 more, I've also tried adding a position update immediately and it still gives me the same result.

Comment: `set_world_position()` should set position and angle after collision detection with a correct bouncing applied.